# how get the correct term_id for each article

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using two plugins **WPCustom Category Image** for Be able to insert an image in each category and **W4 Post List** for list the categories on the screen.

In this moment give me always the last image of categories. I pretend the image of each category corresponding to each ID.

The plugin have one shortcode [term_id] which shows the corresponding category id but i can't use one shortcode inside from another shortcode.

**Example** - [wp_custom_image_category onlysrc="false" size="full" term_id="[term_id"]]

Any solution?

```
foreach( get_categories(['hide_empty' => false]) as $category) {
    $image = do_shortcode('[wp_custom_image_category onlysrc="false" size="full" term_id="'.$category->term_id.'" ]');
    echo $image.'<br/>';

    // $id = 4;
    $options['template'] =
    '[terms]
        <div class="col-sm-3 news-cat-links" id="[term_id]">
            <a href="[term_link]">[term_name]</a><img src="'.$image.'" /></a>
     </div>[/terms]';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to corresponding plugin files and find the functions of `[term_id]` shortcode.

Answer (score 0):

below code returns array of custom texanomy named "eventcategory". define $post as global variable .

```
      $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'eventcategory' );
            if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : 
              $draught_links = array();
             foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    $draught_links[] = $term->name;
                }
         print_r($draught_links);
```